# Angular formGroup, scroll to first Invalid input in a scrolling div

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a significantly large form and the way the application is laid out, the form is in a scrolling div, so I can't use (because it doesn't seem to work) something like:

```
private scrollToFirstInvalidControl() {
        const firstInvalidControl: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(
            "form .ng-invalid"
        );

        firstInvalidControl.focus();
    }
```

This is a one-off thing, I also don't want it as a directive, it's just overkill, I just want to focus on the first invalid object in the formGroup after I run this.form.markAllAsTouched(); and walk away.. smooth scrolling would be a nice bonus, but not a huge deal.

Comment: Does your form have only inputs, or you have other elements too?

Comment: Hi Misha, It has several kendo objects in the form of dropdowns, date pickers and then some plain inputs and textareas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this (change `formId` to actual id of your form:

```
private scrollToFirstInvalidControl() {
    let form = document.getElementById('formId'); // <-- your formID
    let firstInvalidControl = form.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid')[0];
    firstInvalidControl.scrollIntoView();
    (firstInvalidControl as HTMLElement).focus();
}
```

Comment: I did basically that before and it wasn't finding the object by class name, but that time it worked, thank you! Now to add some buffer space to it, but thank you Misha!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for navigating close to *invalid* element:

```js
private scrollToFirstInvalidControl(): void {
    const formElement = elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.form'); // get the form by class name
    
    if (formElement) {
        const firstErrorElement = formElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid'); // get the first error with ng invlalid input class name
        
        if (firstErrorElement) {
            firstErrorElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'nearest' }); // you can also use block: 'start' for closer navigation
        }
    }
}
```